# Random boolean generator for android

Tags: android, boolean

I am trying to create a random (50/50) chance of a case A or case B happen in android and I need it to be as simple and as resource efficient as possible. I've looked through stackoverflow but all I find for random boolean is in C++?

Would appreciate if someone could give me a suggestion as to how to do this, whether with boolean or with strings/integers (since I was told that booleans is a primitive).

I tried the following

```
          public static boolean getRandomBoolean() {
          return Math.random() < 0.5; } 



        boolean atrg = getRandomBoolean();  
          if (atrg = true) 
              { Toast.makeText(cxt, "TRUE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
          else if (atrg = false) 
              { Toast.makeText(cxt, "FALSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
```

But in nearly every case, I tested (>20x), its TRUE?. This is likely a stupid question but is getRandomBoolean a boolean or an int/double? Sorry, I'm very new to android, as you probably guessed.

Comment: This first method definitely works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your random generator is fine, but your toast displaying the result is not.

The problem is in the if-statement where you use a single equals sign (`=`) which is an assignment. The result of this assignment will be true and thus it will never show the "FALSE" toast.

Try this instead.

```
boolean atrg = getRandomBoolean();  
if (atrg) {
    Toast.makeText(cxt, "TRUE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(cxt, "FALSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you check `boolean` in if. `=` is the assignment operator and `==` is used for comparison. You should check like:

```
if(atrg == true)
```

or in case of boolean it  is simply:

```
if(atrg)
```

Your statement:

```
if(atrg = true)
```

assigns `atrg` with `true` and you never get a `false` case.

Answer (score -1):

Just use Math.random(), it will return a value between 0 and 1.. Example below:

```
public static boolean getRandomBoolean() {
       return Math.random() < 0.5;
   }

public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(getRandomBoolean());  
   }
```